# Delete constraint and table

Tags: sql-server

I created table named as Dates and also I inserted value from other table. You can see how look lines of code below

```
--Create table
CREATE TABLE [dimension].[Dates](
     [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
     [Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     [MonthName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
     [Quarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     [MMYYYY] [char](6) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Dates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MMYYYY ASC))

--Insert data
INSERT INTO  [dimension].[Dates] ([Year],[Month],[MonthName],[MonthName], [MMYYYY])
    SELECT DISTINCT [Year],[Month],[MonthName]0,[MonthName], [MMYYYY]
    FROM [dimension].[Date]
```

Additionally I assign foreign key on FACT.FactTable with primary key of this table with this line of code.

```
ALTER TABLE FACT.FactTable
ADD 
FOREIGN KEY (MMYYYY) REFERENCES [DIMENSION].[Dates] (MMYYYY)
```

So far so good. But know I want to delete this table and make again with additional columns. In order to do this I use this command below but can't work.

```
ALTER TABLE DIMENSION.Dates
DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_Dates]

Msg 3725, Level 16, State 0, Line 183
The constraint 'PK_Dates' is being referenced by table 'FactTable', foreign key constraint 'FK__FactTable__MMYYY__33F4B129'.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 183
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

Because this line don't work for me I can use command drop table to delete this table, so can anybody help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not first remove the refering data and _then_ delete your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `DROP` table if there are other tables that are referencing to your `dimension.Dates` table or in other case you cannot `DELETE` data if there are other tables which data are referenced to data in table `FACT.FactTable`. You should first drop `CONSTRAINT` and then drop table.

```
ALTER TABLE FACT.FactTable DROP CONSTRAINT FK__FactTable__MMYYY__33F4B129;
```

Once the constraint is dropped and you don't have any other references to `dimention.Dates` you can execute the following statement:

```
DROP TABLE dimension.Dates;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says the FACT.FactTable's foreign depends on PK_Dates.  Drop that first.  It doesn't look like you can modify it from a quick reading of the documentation.